# mysqli_stmt_bind_param causes fatal error: memory size exhausted

Tags: php, mysql

I *thought* this was a quite simple query:

```
$qry="SELECT taglink, tagtitle, tagshow FROM taglist_main WHERE tag = ?";
if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link,$qry)) {
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"s",$qstring);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt,$taglink,$tagtitle,$tagshow);
    mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
    echo "<p><strong>".mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt)."</strong> entries found, shown below.</p>";                         
    while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
        echo "<li><a href=\"/$taguri\" title=\"$tagtitle\">$tagshow</a></li>";
    }
mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
```

However, php seems to think otherwise. When running the query, I got the following error:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4294967296 bytes) in /home/envoyenv/public_html/envoytest/tags/index.php on line 110
```

when using the `mysql_stmt_bind_param` line. If I leave that line out and adjust the `SELECT` statement to use the string variable `$qstring` directly, I get no results shown on screen (actually, I get **NOTHING** shown on screen, not even the `echo`!)

This isn't a particularly large table (less than 300 rows) and this query should return 10 rows or so (and the `SELECT` statement works fine in `phpmyadmin`, the expected results are returned)

What am I doing wrong?

---

Edit:

I'd already checked to ensure $qstring was actually a string: here's the result of `var_dump`: string(14) "riskassessment"

Comment: Are you on a cPanel server?

Comment: Do this test: $qry="SELECT taglink, tagtitle, tagshow FROM taglist_main WHERE tag = '".$qstring."'"; echo $qry, and post the output plss

Comment: What is the contents of `$qstring`? Can you do a `var_dump($qstring)` and edit it into your question?

Comment: @JustinE - Yes, @robert-rozas - `SELECT taglink, tagtitle, tagshow FROM taglist_main WHERE tag = 'riskassessment'`

Comment: @user2224457 - that seems just plain weird :D - can you add a little extra code? As far as I can tell, you're doing everything correctly; but when the bind is run, it's trying to add something that's 4 gigabytes in size, instead of your string. What happens if you try explicitly binding `'riskassessment'` instead of the string?

Comment: @andrewsi - weird is an understatement.  No difference if I use `riskassessment`.  It gave me an idea though: the problem appears to be in binding the **result** rather than in the **parameter**. Commenting out the line `mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);` appears to have let the query proceed: the query appears to work if the statements `mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt)` and `mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt,$turi,$ttitle,$tshow)` are swapped round.  Thanks all for your suggestions.

Comment: @user2224457 - I'm glad you got that sorted. Could you post it as an answer, and accept it when you're allowed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With help from @andrewsi:

Swap the order of the `mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt,$taglink,$tagtitle,$tagshow);` and `mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);` lines so the code fragment now reads:

```
$qry="SELECT taglink, tagtitle, tagshow FROM taglist_main WHERE tag = ?";
if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link,$qry)) {
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"s",$qstring);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt,$taglink,$tagtitle,$tagshow);
    echo "<p><strong>".mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt)."</strong> entries found, shown below.</p>";                         
    while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
        echo "<li><a href=\"/$taguri\" title=\"$tagtitle\">$tagshow</a></li>";
    }
mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
```

Hopefully this will be useful for those who still like to write procedural code.

Answer (score 0):

This is a PHP Memory error: "Fatal Error" this really has nothing to do with mysql, as mysql would generate a different error. The problem is, PHPMyAdmin runs on a cPanel backend, which has a seperate installation of PHP, and Apache, so the resource limits are set higher. Your PHP Script runs in a seperate php environment with lower specs. I would get with your host to raise your PHP Memory Limit Threshold, or see the link below.

[Raise Memory Limit](http://forums.cpanel.net/f34/memory-limit-244822.html)

Comment: In this case it wasn't.